# Android Custom Linting half working after publishing on remote repository

Tags: android, maven, lint, android-lint

I have an android library for which I created 2 linting rules. In the project there are 3 packages, the main one with a sample app, the lib package, and the linting package. The only link between the lib and the lint modules that I can find, is in the `build.gradle` of the lib

```
    lintPublish(project(':app:linter_pkg'))
```

All is fine and well when I try the linting rules while the lib is brought in the sample like this

```
 implementation project(path: ':app:myLib')
```

But as soon as I publish the library to github packages as a `.aar`, and I bring the lib in the sample app using the remote package, one of the linting rules stops working.

And this doesn't make any sense to me. When the library is brought with local linkage both rules work, so clearly the code works. It doesn't seem like I am publishing the linting rules wrongly, since one of the rules still works. So the `aar` gets downloaded and linked correctly.

I also inspected the build files and `.class` files of what I am published and comapred them with what Android Studio produces when I link the lint locally and they are identical.

Any idea what would cause this sort of behaviour, only half of the build to be broken?

Comment: Can you give us some error and/or log messages?

Comment: I'd be more than happy to if you could tell me how I can get some. This was my first time working with the android linter, I have no idea how to get it to give me logs

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit I am not an Android developer, so please forgive if my answer is not helpful or even wrong, but I have an idea of what went wrong here.

Looking at [Google's example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-custom-lint-rules) of custom lint rules, you will find that they have *not* nested their lint rules under the `app` folder, but into a separate folder named `checks` with using `apply plugin: 'java-library'` in its [`build.gradle`](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-custom-lint-rules/blob/main/checks/build.gradle) and no `android` section. When you nest the lint rules into `app`, I assume that the build information of the app's `build.gradle` is taken into account, which targets the Android runtime (which is not capable of the full Java API). However the lint rules are intended to be run under a *real* JVM/JDK, therefor it should have a completely independent `build.gradle`.

Finally they [publish the lint rules](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-custom-lint-rules/blob/main/library/build.gradle) together with the lib as you did:

```
/** Package the given lint checks library into this AAR  */
dependencies {
    implementation project(':checks')
    lintPublish project(':checks')
}
```

If my answer is wrong, you still might compare your project (and especially the `build.gradle` of the lint rules) with the example and might find some crucial difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this code in your project level `build.gradle`  file .

```
repositories {
maven { url "https://example.com/repo" }
}

dependencies {
lintChecks "com.example:custom-lint-rules:1.0.0"
}
```

and need to add custom lint checks: like:-

```
android {
lintOptions {
    enable 'CustomLintCheck'
}
}
```

it works in my case

Comment: I will try it, might work

Comment: No... unfortunatelly it didn't work. Although, in your example, is the lint module uploaded as a separate dependency? In my case it's published alongside (or at least I think it is) the lib module due to `lintPublish`